# Python-poetry error: Setting settings.virtualenvs.in-project does not exist

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am setting `poetry` to create virtual environments in the project directory.
I entered:

> poetry config settings.virtualenvs.in-project true

and received error

> [ValueError]
>   Setting settings.virtualenvs.in-project does not exist

Also there is the text

> home/alex/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/subprocess32.py:149: RuntimeWarning: The _posixsubprocess module is not being used. Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads.
>     "program uses threads.", RuntimeWarning)

**How can I solve the error?**

It seems that error deals with version of the python.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 version

Poetry version 1.0.5

Comment: Are you using poetry version 0.10.0 or greater? That's the version of poetry that added that setting. Also, I was under the impression poetry only works with python3, which also might be causing you issues.

Comment: @ptd Poetry version 1.0.5

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The config has changed with the release of poetry 1.0. The prefix `settings` is no longer needed. So just type `poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true`.

Concerning the `subprocess` warning: This seems to be just a warning and has no influence on the correct working of poetry. Also have a look at my [comment in poetry's issue tracker](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2106).

@ptd: poetry can work with python2 and python3.

Comment: @finswimmer is it possible to set this configuration in `pyproject.toml`. I tried the below but it wont work 
```
[virtualenvs]
in-project = true
```

Comment: If you run `poetry config` with `--local` option, the config is written to a `poetry.toml` within your project. This file is meant for local configurations and should not be added to the repository.